# IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath is null when using EF7 commands

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

**Problem**

When I try to add a migration to my code, e.g: `dnx ef migrations add initial`,

the `env.WebRootPath` in `Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)` is null.

This will give me compilation errors when adding a new migration or updating the database.

**The Code**

In the *Startup.cs* class I have these lines in the constructor:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // ...
    MyStaticClass.Initialize(env.WebRootPath);
    // ...
    _hostingEnvironment = env;
}
```

Here `env.WebRootPath` is null and in the `Initialize` function this throws an exception.

In the *ConfigureServices* function of the *Startup.cs* I resolve my class dependencies:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddInstance<IMyService>(new MyService(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath))
    // Note: _hostingEnvironment is set in the Startup constructor.
    // ...
}
```

**Notes**

- I can build, run, and deploy the code fine. Everything works!
- However I made a change in the model and want to add a migration with this command: `dnx ef migrations add MyMigration` then I see the compilation errors in the package manager console.
- I am using ASP 5 web application, and Entity Framework 7

Comment: I added wwwroot folder in my application and it worked fine.

Comment: just add app.UseStaticFiles();

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is an issue reported on github regarding my problem:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4494

I used the workaround in the comments now it seems to be working fine:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_env.WebRootPath))
{
   env.WebRootPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot");
}
```

Comment: Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "wwwroot");

Answer (score 67):

The env.WebRootPath can also be null if the wwwroot folder has been inadvertantly removed from the root of your project. Adding a wwwroot folder to the root of your project will also fix this issue.

Comment: I personally encountered this error because I ran `dotnet Path.To.My.Web.Project.dll` from the _solution_ root, which of course didn't have a `wwwroot` folder. Per [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6890#issuecomment-456245144) I tried running the command from the _project_ root, and the error was gone.

Comment: It can also be null when wwwroot exists but is **empty**. In which case adding any file to wwwroot solved it.

Answer (score 15):

This thread is I believe best one to find out the answer for this problem.

**Method 1:**

I spent a bit of time looking for answer and I figured out that the way to sort this out rather than check if path exists(in controller or methods) is to update your Program.cs:

```
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebHost webHost = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

        await webHost.RunAsync();
    }

    private static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseWebRoot("wwwroot")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

This way you will ensure that there will be webroot folder ready for placing files inside it and _environment.webRootPath will not be null and also you can even customize the name of the folder.

**Method 2**

The second option to do this is to manually add "wwwroot" folder in the project from Visual Studio level. The program should pick this up and allocate as wwwroot folder:

[image: Method no 2]

Comment: For me the issue was solved by adding `.UseWebRoot("wwwroot")`. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the problem was that the wwwroot folder was empty and VS didn't recognized it.

The solution: create a placeholder.txt in wwwroot.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If wwwroot folder is empty, env.WebRootPath variable is null.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still faces this problem, in my case the issue was default constructor which I created it for a test.

So, remove the default constructor if any.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error while file uploading in asp.net core application with Telerik controls. The error is not related to Telerik control.

While investigation I got the description that This is the variable which gives the same functionality as `Server.MapPath` given in `asp.net`

Good explanation:- [What is the equivalent of Server.MapPath in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398965/what-is-the-equivalent-of-server-mappath-in-asp-net-core)

```
//this code from above link that how it will be used in the code
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

        return Content(webRootPath + "\n" + contentRootPath);
    }
}
```

This is the actual code which gives me the error, I replace the WebRootPath with another way to solve the issue and it works. you can assign and use in the entire application.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveAsync(IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
        {
            // The Name of the Upload component is "files"
            if (files != null)
            {
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    var fileContent = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition);

                    // Some browsers send file names with full path.
                    // We are only interested in the file name.
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileContent.FileName.ToString().Trim('"'));

                    //The below line gives the error
                    //var physicalPath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "App_Data", fileName);

                    //and I replace with this (but we can use this variable at multiple location by assign a physical path)
                    var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot"), "App_Data", fileName);

                    //The files are not actually saved in this demo
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(physicalPath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Return an empty string to signify success
            return Content("");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same issue but with what seems a unique scenario to this post, so I'll add it.

I have a solution with several nested projects.  Similar to this:

```
> Solution
  > MvcProject
    > wwwroot
    > // etc.
  > SecondMvcProject
  > AnotherMvcProject
```

When running my `MvcProject`, the `IHostingEnvironment` had the `ContentRootPath` set to the `Solution` folder, and the `WebRootPath` was null.

Per other people's answers, adding a `wwwroot` folder in the `Solution` folder made `WebRootPath` have a value, but it was the `Solution` folder path.  I had to modify my launch task's current working directory (`cwd`) in VS Code.  It defaulted to `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"`, and I had to change it to `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/MvcProject"`

**Update**

I had this same problem again on another machine, and was glad I commented on this.  This time, the problem was that we didn't have any files in one of our `wwwroot` folders, and empty folders don't get committed to git repos.  Add a file to your folder, if you need it!

(It was there for consistency with setup for static file handling.  We'll eventually have something in there before the project launches!)