# ASP.Net Core doesn't recognize Request.MapPath in Razor segment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, request

Working with ASP.Net Core is still a little new to me. I'm trying to follow a tutorial on *PluralSight* that details how Image Composition in .NET works.

That said, the code I'm trying to convert from ASP.Net MVC to ASP.Net Core is showing an error on `Request` in my `Index.cshtml`:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ImageFromPath", new { path = Request.MapPath("~/img/1.jpg") })" />
```

The error is simply:

> The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context.

My `HomeController.cs`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ImageFromPath(string path)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(path))
        {
            bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }

        ms.Position = 0;
        return File(ms, "image/jpg");
    }
}
```

In MVC, I can look up definition of `Request` that goes all the way back to `WebPageRenderingBase [from metadata]`, yet this does not exist in .NET Core, can anyone offer a way to get this to work?

**EDIT** - I later plan on using the backend `ImageFromPath` method to return an image from an API call, not the file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just serve the image straight from file system, unless I'm missing something.

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/img/1.jpg")" alt="Some Text" />
```

### Update

> I later plan on using the backend ImageFromPath method to return an
>   image from an API call, not the file system.

You just pass the image filename only, and resolve the full path at server-side.

```
<img src="@Url.Action("ImageFromPath", new { filename = "1.jpg" })" />

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public ActionResult ImageFromPath(string filename)
    {
        string path = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "/img/" + filename;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying your solution - I get an error: `A null reference or invalid value was found [GDI+ status: InvalidParameter]` Any idea why this is the case in Debug/Development-mode? (Could be a different case if publishing to an app service)

Comment: Could you try like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35324326/296861)?

Comment: Does that go into the `ConfigureServices` function or in the actual `StartUp`?

Comment: I never have IHostingEnvironment  null, so I did not get change to test it. You can try both and see what works.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject IHostingEnvironment variable in view and rewrite code like below using **Host** variable:

```
 @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
 @inject IHostingEnvironment Host;

 <img src="@Url.Action("ImageFromPath", new { path = Host.WebRootPath + "/img/1.jpg" })"
```

**UPDATE:**

Did not see **Win's** update message, his solution use the same approach, but more cleaner in terms of separation of concerns than my solution.

Comment: Please do not do that. Malicious user can *easily* find out the directory structure of the web server, and it'll lead to a security hole.