# AS.NET Core Web API after publishing to IIS the WebRootPath always returns blank or empty

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, iis-7

I have built an Angular app with ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API. I have created some reports and stored them under the `Reports` folder under the root. Everything works fine in development.

The `WebRootPath` is always blank (empty string but NOT null) after publishing to IIS, however the `ContentRootPath` returns the root folder path. I'm wondering why the `WebRootPath` is blank after publishing to IIS. I made sure the `wwwroot` folder is included to output directory when published.

Please see my code to get the web hosting environment:

```
private IWebHostEnvironment _hostEnv;

public ReportController(ILoggerManager logger, IReportService reps, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    _hostEnv = env;
}

public IActionResult RunReport()
{
    // other code....
    report.ReportPath = _hostEnv..WebRootPath.Replace("wwwroot", "") + @"\Reports\SalesSummary.rdlc";
    string imagePath  = _hostEnv..WebRootPath + @"\Storage\Invoice\InvLogo.png";
}
```

I'm using the `WebRootPath` as shown above to set report and image path. But the code is not working as the folder path is blank..

The `Reports` folder is in the root folder, and the `Images` folder is inside the `wwwroot` folder.

See the folder structure below (ignore Images folder which is different)

[image]

How do I specify path to reports and other content in ASP.NET Core? Is `wwwroot` folder is compulsory?

Please help.

UPDATE:
After publishing to IIS the rest of the application works fine. Only issue with reports and images path. The error I'm getting is **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**" because the `_hostEnv.WebRootPath` is returning empty string.

This is the publish folder. and its contents. 
[image]

[image]

I published my app outside the default "inetpub" folder. I'm not sure
if wwwroot is still relevant. Can I start using ContentRootPath instead and ignore webrootpath?

Comment: Publishing files to various folders inside wwwroot of a web server is not compulsory!  This is just the default location that IIS assigns because Windows is configured by default to have this folder with the proper security for IIS to access the files.  If you go to security of wwwroot, you will notice there is a user named IIS AppPool\<apppool name>.  If you were to move the files elsewhere in Windows, you just need this same user assigned the contents of the web folder.  And the IIS app needs access to it as well.  The publishing can happen manually or automatically (in your case).

Comment: If you launch in debug mode, can you see the web application fine?  Typically if publishing, a random port is chosen and it is usually only accessible from the tool that randomly chose the port.  If you publish manually, you have more control and the URL of your site will always be the same.  Port 80 is default.  Port 443 is if you have an SSL certificate.  If testing on localhost, you can choose any port by configuring in IIS.  http://localhost:8080/index.html for example.

Comment: In all honesty, I'd create a simple index.html website with IIS first.  Once you know IIS is running, then proceed to publishing this code manually.  Thirdly, if the manual publishing succeeded to IIS, proceed with the automatic publishing, which is what you are doing, which requires an API.  Using an API without learning to do something manually can be torture if you've never called into an API before.

Comment: Another thing to note.  If you are publishing locally to the computer you're developing the site on, you don't need to worry about opening up firewall ports.  If it's on a real server, you will need to do this as an extra step.

Comment: Okay, another thing to note.  You will need to go to Control Panel > Services > IIS Web Publishing Service and make sure the IIS service is running/started and not stopped.

Comment: Can you post the errors/exceptions you are getting?  That will allow others to help you.

Comment: @MacGyver many thanks for looking into my question. To answer your questions...the rest of the application works fine, only the reports and images not working due to path issues. I have added logging to see at which step it's failing and found out that the _hostEnv.WebRootPath is returning blank. I will update the question with few more details.

Comment: Someone previously suggested to add wwwroot folder to my Web API project and that way I can get relative path to reports and images. So confusing. If I ignore wwwroot, how will I refer to the Reports path.

Comment: Many thanks for making me aware of the other issues I need to focus when I publish this site properly outside of my dev environment.

Comment: Use "AppContext.BaseDirectory" (this is the directory you're code is running from) If you are just linking to resources you can use "~" in the path which is accessible via URL (wwwroot directory).  If you are serving files it's better to use AppContext.BaseDirectory (+foldername) and have the controller serve the file (return File).   This would not be reachable via link so that you can prevent deep links and check for authorization.

Comment: "wwwroot" is created when publishing... it's common for this to have things like images, javascripts, and css files.  (anything with src="~/..." will be there.  The core executable/assembly will be one directory above it... it will serve up the pages (output of .cshtml files)

Comment: @MSBI-Geek, you're welcome.  The error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." means the object is null.  Meaning either (1) the object _hostEnv is null ... or ... (2) _hostEnv.WebRootPath is null.  Likely #1 since WebRootPath is not an object.  WebRootPath is probably a property (with string data type) of the C# class of the instantiated object named _hostEnv.  We know the string property is blank.  So I would find out where _hostEnv variable/object originates from and find out why it's null.  If the object is null, it can't have a property because it doesn't exist.

Comment: You may spend hours trying to track down this issue because you're dealing with object oriented classes.  In the meantime, just set the two paths directly without using the _hostEnv object as a temporary workaround, because we know _hostEnv is null.  Do report.ReportPath = @"\path_to_reports\" and do the same for the other path.  Meaning remove this part.  _hostEnv..WebRootPath.Replace("wwwroot", "").  Let us know the outcome.

Comment: And it's not a huge deal if you fix correctly because you won't publish the website to testing or production with this method.  I would focus on manual publishing to learn the details of IIS.  Just realize IIS has two ways to create a website.  Via an application and via a website.  There are differences when configuring.

Comment: If you want to get the actual fix, this is a good reference.  Again, object oriented programming concepts that must be understood first.  Interfaces are tricky.  https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-WebRootPath-and-ContentRootPath-in-ASPNet-Core.aspx

Comment: @MacGyver Thanks again. For me the _hostEnv is NOT null just the webrootpath is blank. The other properties of the _hostEnv works fine. So I started using ContentRootPath which works fine. I will continue to use that whilst I learn more about publishing to IIS manually. Thanks for the snippets link too..

Comment: You're welcome.  Try both relative paths and absolute paths.  I'm not sure what they allow when publishing to IIS.  Some software requires a relative path to begin with ~\path and some begin with \path and some with path (without \).  Try all three.  On Linux, relative paths can be ./path or /path or path (without /).  Notice backslashes for Windows and forward slashes for Linux.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35324326/640205